# Correlation of a nominally scaled variable and another of interval scale type

Tags: correlation

I have two variables A and B.

A is of nominal scale type and B is of interval scale type.

A is the brand of the car a person drives.
And B is the person's mean salary per year.

What method would you recommend to measure the correlation?

Comment: Please add more details. Calculating correlations is only the first step, so the question depends on what are you going to do with these correlations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually **eta** or its shrunk version **omega** are used as a measure of strength of relationship between a nominal and an interval variables. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) for short reference. You might consider taking logarithm of your interval variable income before computation.

Comment: that's the hint I needed!