# Dependence measure for categorical and numerical

Tags: correlation, mutual-information

I have a very basic question, but I am having difficulties finding an answer.

What would be a simple measure of dependency between a categorical and a numerical variable?

For two numericals it could be a linear correlation coefficient, for two categoricals - mutual information. But I don't want to discretize the numerical variable, or convert the categorical variable into numerical.

Comment: Is your question different from a number of posted already, such as [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20022/3277) or [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/73065/3277). By the way, which of the two variables - nominal or interveal - is the dependent one?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these answers. If I understand correctly, computing "eta" coefficient requires discretization of the numerical variable, that is, converting into intervals. I am interested, if there is a simple measure that would work with raw numerical variable.

Comment: The numerical variable is the dependent one.

Comment: Eta is for numeric as the dependent, and requires no discretization of it.